# Stuck at CyanogenMod recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab p3100 and i can't flash anything. All I have is a Stock CyanogenMod recovery and i can't even go through odin and install a new cwm/twrp. I don't know why but it says USB device is not recognized :(

I've tried to uninstall the usb thing in device manager but no luck. My only chance is flash a rom or a SIGNED cwm/twrp (i guess i'm running out of options) for my device but i can't find any signed zip file to be flashed on cyanogenmod recovery please help.

Comment: and i did buy a new usb cable but still not working :( help pls im dying..

Answer (score 1):

You can install TWRP with root access without the need of a PC.

1. Download the latest image for your device [here](https://dl.twrp.me/p3100/).
2. Your phone needs to be turned on.
3. Copy the recovery IMG to the root of your sdcard and rename it to `twrp.img`.
4. Open a terminal application and execute this command: `su -c "dd if=/sdcard/twrp.img of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p6"`
5. The custom TWRP recovery is now installed.

> **Note**: Do not use this guide for any other devices, it will be bricked.

---

The reason your device isn't recognised on your PC is probably because you have Windows 8/8.1/10 installed. The drivers (ADB) for Android phones do not work correctly yet. There are some workarounds  on the internet.

Comment: Hmm, about that .. I can't reboot my device up and open a terminal application because that's my problem too i mean i formatted system thru cm recovery i did that because I'm stuck at the logo, and i am using windows 7  os, i did try to plug my device on other pc from my friend but no luck.

Comment: and also IDK why that cm recovery just appeared i didn't touch anything on dev settings when my tab is working before..